# How is blank defined in C?

Tags: c, whitespace

I want to get a string as input by using `scanf` and if the string is just a space or blank I have to print error message.

This is what I've tried to do:

```
char string1[20]
scanf("%s",string1)
if(string1=='')
   print error message
```

But that didn't work, actually I didn't expect it to work because `string1` is an array of chars.

Any hint how to do it?

Comment: Check the [`isspace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isspace) function.

Comment: `''` is an ill-defined entity.  If there were some character between the quotes, it would be an int.  You cannot compare an array of char to an int.  If you want to determine that `string1` is the empty string, you want to check if `string1[0] == '\0'`

Answer (score 5):

You should note that the `scanf` function will *never* scan a string with only blanks in it. Instead check the return value of the function, if it's (in your case) less than one it failed to read a string.

---

You may want to use [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) to read a line, remove the trailing newline, and then check if each character in the string is a space (with the [`isspace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isspace)  function).

Like this:

```
char string1[20];
if (fgets(string1, sizeof(string1), stdin) != NULL)
{
    /* Remove the trailing newline left by the `fgets` function */
    /* This is done by changing the last character (which is the newline)
     * to the string terminator character
     */
    string1[strlen(string1) - 1] = '\0';

    /* Now "remove" leading whitespace */
    for (char *ptr = string1; *ptr != '\0' && isspace(*ptr); ++ptr)
        ;

    /* After the above loop, `*ptr` will either be the string terminator,
     * in which case the string was all blanks, or else `ptr` will be
     * pointing to the actual text
     */
    if (*ptr == '\0')
    {
        /* Error, string was empty */
    }
    else
    {
        /* Success, `ptr` points to the input */
        /* Note: The string may contain trailing whitespace */
    }
}
```

Comment: what to you mean in checking the return value of the function? which function?

Comment: @somebody The `scanf` call. You may want to read e.g. [this reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf).

Comment: Note: Although highly unlikely, `string1[strlen(string1) - 1] = '\0'` can fail dramatically if the first byte of the string is `\0`.  Example: piped input with embedded NULs.

Answer (score 1):

`scanf()` does *not* always skip leading blanks.

Select formats specifies like "`%s`", "`%d`", "`%f`" *do* skip leading blanks. (whitespace).
Other formats specifies like "`%c`", "`%[]`", "`%n`" do *not* skip skip leading whitespace.

Scan in line and look for spaces.  (string1 may contain whitespace)

```
char string1[20];
// Scan in up to 19 non-LineFeed chars, then the next char (assumed \n)
int result = scanf("%19[^\n]%*c", string1);
if (result < 0) handle_IOError_or_EOF();
else if (result == 0) handle_nothing_entered();
else {
  const char *p = string1;
  while (isspace(*p)) p++;
  if (*p == '\0') 
    print error message
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, `scanf` will **skip any blank spaces** if you put a space (or other white space characters like `'\n'` or `'\t'`) before the format specifier, like `scanf(" %s", &str)`

Second, `if(string1=='')` will compare the char pointer `string1` with the blank char `''` which will **never be true** because an existing variable's address will be non-NULL. That said, there's no *"blank"* char like that `''` in C. You need to get the line input and parse whether it is a blank line or contains only spaces